# Finding the process that use network traffic

Tags: networking, centos

With `nethogs`, I able to see that there is traffic from one node to another.

```
NetHogs version 0.8.5

    PID USER     PROGRAM                                                DEV        SENT      RECEIVED
      ? root     10.10.10.1:2049-10.10.10.253:873                               12090.597      66.006 KB/sec
  27592 mahmood  ssh                                                    eth0        0.035       0.645 KB/sec
  ? root     10.10.10.1:809-10.10.10.252:15002                                  0.000       0.000 KB/sec
  ? root     10.10.10.1:805-10.10.10.251:15002                                  0.000       0.000 KB/sec
  ? root     10.10.10.1:804-10.10.10.252:15002                                  0.000       0.000 KB/sec
  ? root     172.16.48.70:9618-10.10.10.251:43431                               0.000       0.000 KB/sec
  3193 sge      /opt/gridengine/bin/linux-x64/sge_qmaster              eth0        0.000       0.000 KB/sec
  ? root     unknown TCP                                                        0.000       0.000 KB/sec
```

But I am not able to figure out which process is causing that traffic. Any idea about that?

Please note that according to the output of nethogs, :2049 on 10.10.10.1 (server) and :873 on 10.10.10.253 (compute-0-1) are communicating.

So, On the server

```
root@cluster:~# netstat -anp | grep 2049
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2049                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -
tcp     1540 3461276 10.10.10.1:2049             10.10.10.253:873            ESTABLISHED -                  
tcp        0      0 10.10.10.1:2049             10.10.10.252:683            ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 10.10.10.1:2049             10.10.10.251:1012           ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 :::2049                     :::*                        LISTEN      -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2049                0.0.0.0:*                               -
udp        0      0 :::2049                     :::*                                    -
```

And on compute-0-1:

```
[root@compute-0-1 ~]# netstat -anp | grep 873
tcp        0 3339056 10.10.10.253:873            10.10.10.1:2049             ESTABLISHED -
```

So the process names are not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You will never see a process name for a service handled by the kernel itself, such as the NFS server, which is what runs on TCP port 2049 (and UDP 2049, but you usually shouldn't use UDP for NFS).